# Finding SP 500 index members with Rbbg package for specific date

Tags: bloomberg

I'm trying to extract the index members of the S&P 500 Index for a specific date in time with the help of the Bloomberg package Rbbg:

Here is a small example which will provide me with the SP500 constituents of today:

configurations

```
index <- "SPX Index" 

Sys.setenv(TZ="GMT")

require(Rbbg)
require(tcltk)
library(rJava)

date <- as.POSIXct("1990-01-01")
```

connection to bloomberg station

`conn <- blpConnect(jvm.params = c("-Xmx256m", "-Xloggc:rbloomberg.gc", "-XX:+PrintGCDetails"))`

members of index and their tickers

```
 tickers <- bds(conn, index, "INDX_MEMBERS")[,1]
```

Now I would like to insert a specific date into the bds() function, so that I get the index constituents as of January 1, 1990.

Thank you for your help.
Best Regards
Jann

Comment: FOUND THE SOLUTION: tickers <- bds(conn, index, "INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST", override_fields = c("END DT"), override_values = c("20000101") )

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution although it is not very flexible. With our HistIndexTickers function you can get historical tickers out in a matrix for any time frequency you want. The output is a matrix with zeroes and ones indicating whether the ticker was part of the index or not at any given date.

```
> require(RbbgExtension)
> require(quantmod)
> 
> hist.tickers <- HistIndexTickers(index = "SPX",
+                                  startdate = "20140101",
+                                  freq = "MONTHLY")
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) 
rJava Version 0.9-6 
Rbbg Version 0.5.3 
Java environment initialized successfully.
Looking for most recent blpapi3.jar file...
Adding C:\blp\API\APIv3\JavaAPI\v3.7.1.1\lib\blpapi3.jar to Java classpath
Bloomberg API Version 3.7.1.1 
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) 
rJava Version 0.9-6 
Rbbg Version 0.5.3 
Java environment initialized successfully.
Looking for most recent blpapi3.jar file...
Adding C:\blp\API\APIv3\JavaAPI\v3.7.1.1\lib\blpapi3.jar to Java classpath
Bloomberg API Version 3.7.1.1 
[1] "Finding historical tickers for SPX on..."
2014-01-31 
2014-02-28 
2014-03-31 
2014-04-30 
2014-05-30 
2014-06-30 
2014-07-31 
2014-08-29 
2014-09-30 
2014-10-31 
2014-11-28 
2014-12-31 
2015-01-30 
> dim(hist.tickers)
[1]  13 517
> hist.tickers[,1:6]
           A US AA US AAPL US ABBV US ABC US ABT US
2014-01-31    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-02-28    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-03-31    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-04-30    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-05-30    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-06-30    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-07-31    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-08-29    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-09-30    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-10-31    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-11-28    1     1       1       1      1      1
2014-12-31    1     1       1       1      1      1
2015-01-30    1     1       1       1      1      1
```